# Can I install new software for eclipse without using mirrors?

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded the latest eclipse plugin developer package and am now trying to add new features using `Install new software`.

After selecting `Neon releases`, I chose `XML editors` and started the download. I get a 503 error.

The URL requested is `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201612211000/plugins/org.apache.xerces_2.9.0.v201101211617.jar` but in Wireshark I see that the actual server is `http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/eclipse//releases/neon/201703231000/plugins/org.apache.xerces_2.9.0.v201101211617.jar`.

It looks like eclipse is redirecting to a mirror.

I am behind a company firewall etc and `eclipse.org` has been added to the trustworthy sites but the mirrors not.

It is possible to tell eclipse to only use `eclipse.org` and not to use mirrors?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=329240) the redirect seems to be a decision of `eclipse.org` based on current available bandwidth and not of your local Eclipse. Unfortunately it will choose random mirrors. So if this information is still correct the answer to your question is no.

As a workaround you could convince your admin to treat `ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de` as trustworthy site and add a corresponding repository location for that site in your Eclipse. Or download the installation files in a non-slaved environment and install from a local repository location.